# No Show Webpage Option when Opening New Application

Tags: macos, security, monterey, gatekeeper

I was setting up my Macbook for some coding development, and wanted to install chrome, github desktop, and visual studio code. When I added Chrome to my Applications folder and double clicked, it gave the option to open, show webpage, close. However, when I open either github desktop or visual studio code, I do not get the option to show webpage. Is this normal, or are these apps possibly malicious (i.e. not from real sources)? I have included a screenshot of opening Visual Studio code.

[image]

Comment: Where did you download Github Desktop and Visual Studio Code from?

Comment: @nohillside from https://desktop.github.com for github desktop. It seems like the official site

Comment: Indeed, and VSCode from Microsoft? So why should this be malware?

Comment: @nohillside it's just that, for google chrome for instance, usually macos gives you a "show web page" option, but I have no clue why that option is not present for these two applications

Comment: I honestly might just use the 'erase content and settings' feature just to be safe. After looking through youtube videos of people installing these softwares they are getting the web option that I am not getting. No clue why, might be worth it though especially since there isn't a lot on this computer

Comment: I just tried with Visual Studio Code, downloaded from https://code.visualstudio.com/. Got the message with the "Show Webpage Part"

Comment: Yeah this is really bad, why did I not get it. Is it because it was M1?

Comment: It's weird, I run spctl assess on them and they seem legit. Why don't they have the option?

Comment: (same for Github) I also have an M1

Comment: Wait @nohillside are you downloading the m1 specific version of VSCode or the universal one? Apparently universal brings up the show web prompt but not the m1 specific

Comment: I get the webpage prompt for both the universal and the m1 specific version of VSCode. Honestly, if you downloaded from the official sites I would assume other reasons for this than somebody trying to fool you. But don't take my word for it :-)

Comment: It's honestly just super weird why on some versions it works and some it does not